# Broken tags, no question preview, and "silent fail"

Tags: bug, tags, asking-questions

There are a few bugs I am encountering with this site today:

- It appears the tagging system is broken, making it very difficult to ask questions, which may explain the low question rate on this site.  It highlights previous search terms, instead of potential tags when I enter the tags.  I can mitigate this by looking at previous questions and picking a tag to start with.  When I go back to edit a question, it lets me add tags properly.
- Question preview is not displaying as I type my question
- When I try to post the question with incorrect tags, it "fails" silently without giving an error message.

Notes: I use Firefox, and this has worked properly in the past using Firefox.

Comment: FWIW....I'm doing fine in FF, just edited your question and tags without encountering problems #1 or #2. I didn't try for #3. (I don't know how to help resolve your issues, though, sorry - someone else will surely chime in.)

Comment: Also FWIW (and to confirm) - I'm also in FF (33, on Linux Mint at the moment), and everything's fine. Like Susan♦ I didn't go so far as to try posting, but preview and tag-autocomplete was working nicely. Looks to be something askew at your end, Jonathan. =/

Comment: And I'm on FF on Windows 7 and also not having any issues - are yours still persisting?

Comment: Yes, it is still going on for me.

Comment: Have you got any FireFox add-ons like NoScript enabled? I'd try disabling them all as a test. Btw I only got your reply by chance - you need to `@Jack` me to make sure a reply goes to my inbox.

Comment: Can you [start FireFox in Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) as a test to see if it is some addon, userscript or configuration issue on your end? If you can ruse that out I would suspect you have a corrupted cache (something like an old JS file that handles completion paired against a new version of the page that doesn't use it properly. Sometimes clock issues on your local system can cause this sort of thing, as can any third party software that interferes with your internet connection (proxies, firewalls, etc.)

Comment: @Caleb I can't figure out how to start Firefox in safe mode.  I am not seeing the "firefox" button that it talks about...